# Uncaught SyntaxError while using setInterval Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am using the below code to play an audio file for every second, the audio file is a second long and it basically a tick. The code will run only once  and then I see the error in the console. My intention is to make it run every second until something is achieve then I can clear the Interval. This is the error I am getting in the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
setInterval (async)
```

This is my code:

```
    $('select[name=notsound]').change(function(){
    var h = $(this).val();
    var tickAudio = new Audio('https://www.sample.com/sounds/'+h+'');
    setInterval(tickAudio.play(),1000);
    });
```

I am not sure why is this happening, I am sure that I have made some error which is causing this issue, as it was working before I thought of giving it a different approach. Thank you for reading my query. :)

Comment: You may want `setInterval(tickAudio.play, 1000)` without the extra `()`, otherwise you'll be calling the result of `tickAudio.play()` every second.

Comment: try to pass callback but not it's result `setInterval(tickAudio.play,1000);`

Comment: When I do that I get this error  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Illegal invocation

Comment: `setInterval(tickAudio.play(),1000);` => `setInterval(tickAudio.play.bind(tickAudio),1000);` or `setInterval(function() { tickAudio.play(); },1000);`, see the linked question's answers for why.

Comment: you are using interval/timeout to make sure video is loaded before play(), better to remove it and use load event instead: 
    $('select[name=notsound]').change(function(){
        var h = $(this).val();
        var tickAudio = new Audio();
        tickAudio.onload = function(){
            tickAudio.play();
        }
        tickAudio.src ='https://www.sample.com/sounds/'+h+'';
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `play` needs to be called in the context of the right object:

```
var cleartick = setInterval(tickAudio.play.bind(tickAudio),1000);
```

The second suggestion of @rmlan will also work.

Clearing interval is the same - you need not to call a function, but to pass a function reference to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(clearInterval, 3000, cleartick);
```

`setInterval`/`setTimeout` have a convenient way of passing parameters to timer functions - as `cleartick` above.

Comment: Yes, this works for me and the second suggestion of rmlan as well. The problem is that I am trying to clear the Interval as well. This is what I am doing and it is wrong for sure.
var cleartick = setInterval(tickAudio.play.bind(tickAudio),1000);;

setTimeout(clearInterval(cleartick), 3000);
I am not good at Js.

Comment: Thanks! This works for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are currently "executing" the result of `tickAudio.play()` every second, instead of executing the function itself.

To remedy this, you can either pass the function as an object:

```
setInterval(tickAudio.play.bind(tickAudio),1000);
```

Or wrap the call in an anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function () { tickAudio.play() },1000);
```

Comment: The second one works and it is looping a tick sound, I am also trying to use the setTimeout to clear the interval after 3 secs. I don't think this is working to clear the interval.
var cleartick = setInterval(function () { tickAudio.play() },1000);

setTimeout(clearInterval(cleartick), 3000);

seems like I am making the same mistake?

Comment: This seems like a separate question that you should ask if you are still having trouble.